# How to get assign a number from a list - JDBC JAVA SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am having trouble with my database where I want to select from a range of stock (not a primary key) and assign them to the users in the system.

For example, I have a field called stockCodes which consists of codes like CAB001-CAB100. This is not the primary key, and the primary key is in fact stockID.

The table looks like this...

```
ID | Stock Codes
--------------------
1  | CAB001-CAB100
2  | CBA100-CBA200
```

Now, how do I break down the stock codes so that I get a list like this in Java...

CAB001

CAB002

CAB003

CAB004

CAB005

...

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a range of data and then displaying all the numbers in that range. How do I that in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512144/getting-a-range-of-data-and-then-displaying-all-the-numbers-in-that-range-how-d)

Comment: So, you have a `String` that contains `"CAB001-CAB100"` and you want to split it into `"CAB001"` and `"CAB100"` and then generate all the values in between (`"CAB002"`, `"CAB003"`, etc.) What does this have to do with databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to parse the text -- do they always follow the same format of 3 letters and 3 digits? If so, something to this effect would work:

```
/**
 * Populate a full list of stocks from a given range
 * 
 * @param stockRange the stock range pulled from the DB, in this format: "XXX###-XXX###"
 * @return list of all stocks in the specified range
 */
public List<String> getFullStockRange(final String stockRange) {
    final String[] values = stockRange.split("-"); 
    final Integer first = Integer.parseInt(values[0].substring(3));
    final Integer last = Integer.parseInt(values[1].substring(3));
    final String prefix = values[0].substring(0, 3);

    final List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = first; i<= last; i++) {
        final String entry = String.format("%s%03d", prefix, i);
        list.add(entry);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Use `String.format("%s%03d", prefix, i)` to avoid creating an extra, unnecessary `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @SamJones I keep getting errors when using List. It keeps saying'type List does not take any parameters'. I used LinkedList instead of List in the end and keep getting java.lang.NumberFormatException error. I think its because some coupon codes are like 101230 for drinks. Many thanks for your help. I would greatly appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.
Oh yeah sorry, I changed the coupon such that the first three digits of the coupon are 101, and then the the next six digits are unique.

Comment: @user3438012 Well, if the situation is more complicated you'll have to build the logic to handle it. I'm not sure exactly what you've changed here -- it would help if you updated the description to match.

Comment: @SamJones lets say the first 3 digits will be CAB..then followed by 8 numbers like 00000001 - 99999999
so CAB00000001-CAB99999999 how do we re-arrange the code you gave above to match this? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: @user3438012 that's just changing the number of digits to zero-pad your number -- that should be easy to figure out from the code I posted. (see the String.format line)

Comment: @SamJones Thank you very much that helped me out a lot.
One more question....now that i got the range sorted how do I go about  selecting from them (e.g: CAB0032300...) and assigning them to users. If you don't know it's no problem, you already helped me out a significant amount.